# В чем заключается ошибка в SQL запросе?

Tags: mysql, sql

Почему этот запрос выдает ошибку (*#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'of France’  AND Countries . name = ‘France’  )  AND  (   Landmarks . top_c' at line* 1):

```
SELECT
*
FROM
Landmarks
INNER JOIN
Localities
ON Landmarks.locality_id = Localities.locality_id
INNER JOIN
Regions
ON Localities.region_id = Regions.region_id
INNER JOIN
Countries
ON Regions.country_id = Countries.country_id
WHERE
(
Localities.name = ‘Normandy’
AND Regions.name = ‘North of France’
AND Countries.name = ‘France’
)
AND
(

Landmarks.top_choice = 1
OR Landmarks.history = 1
OR Landmarks.military = 1
)
AND
( Landmarks.car = 1 )
```

а точно такой же код, но отформатированный, не выдает ошибку:

```
    SELECT
   * 
FROM
   Landmarks 
   INNER JOIN
      Localities 
      ON Landmarks.locality_id = Localities.locality_id 
   INNER JOIN
      Regions 
      ON Localities.region_id = Regions.region_id 
   INNER JOIN
      Countries 
      ON Regions.country_id = Countries.country_id 
WHERE
   (
      Localities.name = 'Normandy' 
      AND Regions.name = 'North of France' 
      AND Countries.name = 'France' 
   )
   AND 
   (
      Landmarks.top_choice = 1 
      OR Landmarks.history = 1 
      OR Landmarks.military = 1 
   )
   AND 
   (
      Landmarks.car = 1 
   )
```

?

Comment: по-моему дело в "неправильных" кавычках...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В [MySQL строковый](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/char.html) тип данных обрамляется в одинарный апостроф - `'some text'`, поэтому вы и получаете ошибку.